# Scrapy all response in single row

Tags: python, for-loop, scrapy

I am new to Scrapy and I’ve seen other queries related to this but my problem seems to be this:

Either my code results in all responses of a page being recorded in a single row or if I use the for loop command, there are multiple responses but each contains all the different items of that page.

```
import scrapy
from ..items import Sephora3Item 

class SephoraSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'sephora3_spider'
    page_number = 2
    start_urls = ['https://www.sephora.com/shop/foundation-makeup?currentPage=1']

    def parse(self, response):
        foundation_full = response.css('a.css-ix8km1')
        items = Sephora3Item()
        items['brand_name'] = foundation_full.css('span.css-ktoumz::text').extract()
        items['p_name'] = foundation_full.css('span.css-pelz90::text').extract()
        items['p_price'] = foundation_full.css('.css-68u28a .css-0').css('::text').extract()
        items['p_category'] = foundation_full.css('.css-uwcqpa .css-fgy0ne').css('::text').extract()

        yield items
            
        next_page = 'https://www.sephora.com/shop/foundation-makeup?currentPage='+str(SephoraSpiderSpider.page_number)
        if SephoraSpiderSpider.page_number <= 4:
        SephoraSpiderSpider.page_number += 1 
        yield response.follow(next_page, callback = self.parse)
```

The output comes in the form of `[brand_name,p_category,p_name,p_price]` but its essentially all `brand_names` from page1 separated by commas, then `categories`, then `names` and then `prices`. Similarly, this repeats for pages2,3 and 4. I want it to simply be `brand_names` in one column, with the associated `p_name`, `category` and `price` next to it.

Comment: Could you please show your output of what you don't think is right? I'm finding hard to follow what you mean by the responses being recorded in a single row. Also what are you wanting to do with thet data ? As in are you going to output this to a table ?

Comment: Aaron, I added the details. I want to get this data in a table format to compare products.

Answer (score 0):

So a couple of things with the code you've got as well as some information on items. I wasn't really able to get your CSS selectors to work, so I would check you have the right ones.

### Corrections to Code

1. The variable `foundation_full` is directed to HTML of all of the products on the page. You need to loop this variable, as you are wanting to extract the contents of each product.
2. Instantiate the items dictionary before you loop. By writing `items = Sephora3Item()` you are creating the items dictionary. This dictionary will store any fields and the respective values, no matter how many values you want to add. There's no need to keep instantiating it on every loop.
3. Use `get()` in with your css selectors not `extract()`, extract() will grab you a list and not a single piece of data which is what you want.

### Code Example

```
def parse(self, response):
        
        items = Sephora3Item()
        foundation_full = response.css('xxx')
        for a in foundation_full:
            
            items['brand_name'] = a.css('xxx').get()
            items['p_name'] = a.css('xxx').get()
            items['p_price'] = a.css('xxx').get()
            items['p_category'] = a.css('xxx').get()
            yield items
            
        next_page = 'https://www.sephora.com/shop/foundation-makeup?currentPage='+str(SephoraSpiderSpider.page_number)
        if SephoraSpiderSpider.page_number <= 4:
            SephoraSpiderSpider.page_number += 1 
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Also don't forget that you should use the CSV output. `Scrapy crawl sephora3_spidder -o test.csv` for example.

The reason you were getting 'rows' as you put it, is that you were using the extract() method which always gives you a list. In the scrapy documentation, they encourage you to use get() for a single value, and getall() for multiple values for a given CSS selector.

### Additional Information on Items

The way Scrapy extracts data is through the items, that is a python object that is defined by the key-value relationship. There are several item types that Scrapy will allow, dictionaries is probably the most familiar but almost always not the best of choices particulary as when data is messy, it provides almost no support to give reasonable outputs.

That support of different types is through something called the itemadapter library. See [here](https://github.com/scrapy/itemadapter) for the github to itemadapter. The rationale for this was that whatever way you want to extract data it pays for that data to be handle in a uniform manner. Through itemadapter library this provides that uniformity.

An itemadapter library instantiates an `ItemAdapter` class and the respective object that is dictionary,items object,dataclass and attributes objects are handled in a dictionary like way. But importantly things like default values can be set or it handles none values for certain fields well. Scrapy does this all under the hood, so when you instantiate an Item Object as you do when you do `items = Sephora3Item()` this is done for you.